# How do i change theme and then build my app?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I am using `provider` to handle my app themeing.
This is my main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import './providers/theme_manager.dart';

//screens
import './screens/home_screen.dart';
import './screens/news_screen.dart';
import './screens/department_screen.dart';
import './screens/contact_us_screen.dart';
import './screens/admission_screen.dart';
import './screens/placements_screen.dart';
import './screens/about_screen.dart';
import './screens/settings_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ThemeManager(),
      child: SfitApp(),
    ),
);

class SfitApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ThemeManager>(builder: (context, themeManager, _) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: "SFIT App",
        theme: themeManager.themeData,
        //routes
        initialRoute: HomeScreen.routeName,
        routes: {
          HomeScreen.routeName: (context) => HomeScreen(),
          AboutScreen.routeName: (context) => AboutScreen(),
          NewsScreen.routeName: (context) => NewsScreen(),
          AdmissionScreen.routeName: (context) => AdmissionScreen(),
          DepartmentScreen.routeName: (context) => DepartmentScreen(),
          PlacementsScreen.routeName: (context) => PlacementsScreen(),
          ContactUsScreen.routeName: (context) => ContactUsScreen(),
          //other
          SettingsScreen.routeName: (context) => SettingsScreen(),
        },
      );
    });
  }
}
```

What happens if when i open my app for the first time. It builds my app with a light theme and then rebuilds if i have set to dark theme. Thus there is a moment where my app is light. Is there a way to rebuild with the set theme.
This is the code for my provider.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../constants/app_themes.dart';

class ThemeManager with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData _themeData;
  final _kThemePreference = "";
  String _theme = 'Light';

  ThemeManager() {
    _loadTheme();
  }

  void _loadTheme() {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((preference) {
      int preferredTheme = preference.getInt(_kThemePreference) ?? 0;
      _themeData = appThemeData[AppTheme.values[preferredTheme]];
      if (AppTheme.values[preferredTheme] == AppTheme.Dark) {
        _theme = 'Dark';
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  ThemeData get themeData {
    if (_themeData == null) {
      _themeData = appThemeData[AppTheme.Light];
    }
    return _themeData;
  }

  String enumName(AppTheme enumValue) {
    return enumValue.toString().split('.')[1];
  }

  String get theme {
    return _theme;
  }

  set themeValue(String theme) {
    _theme = theme;
  }

  setTheme(AppTheme theme) async {
    _themeData = appThemeData[theme];
    notifyListeners();
    var preference = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    preference.setInt(_kThemePreference, AppTheme.values.indexOf(theme));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
If you use shared preferences in void main to load your theme preference then there will be a brief moment where your app will load with the light of default theme and then change to your chosen theme. To prevent this just add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` to your `void main()`.
eg.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  //Initialize Shared Preferences instance
  var preference = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  //Get Theme data
  int preferredTheme = preference.getInt("themePreference") ?? 0;


  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeManager>(
          create: (_) => ThemeManager(preferredTheme),
        ),
      ],
      child: SfitApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```